# jQuery Mobile dialog loads javascript twice

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm clearly doing something wrong.

A simple JQM page with a dialog.  Launching the dialog reloads the JS in the page <head>

The problem made clearer by the additional setTimeout firing every time a dialog is opened (see code below)

Looking at similar questions I don't understand enough to know if it is the same issue.. Nothing I've seen so far has fixed it

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Page </title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('pageinit', 'body', function(event) {
                var jqxhr_alerts;
                function doSomething() {
                    console.log('fire!');
                    console.log('-');
                    interVal=self.setTimeout(function(){doSomething()},3000);
                }
                doSomething();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="top">
        <div data-role="page" id="pagemain">
            <div    data-role="header"
            id="header-0001"
            data-position="fixed"
            >
                <h1 data-inline="true">Page</h1>
            </div><!-- end header-0001 -->
            <div    data-role="content"
            id="content-0001"
            >
                <h2>JS Reload</h2>
                    <a  href="dialog.html"
                        data-rel="dialog"
                        data-ajax="true"
                        id="menuSettings" > Open dialog </a>
                    </li>
                <p>This page has a 3 second interval function 
                    and a dialog link to the contents of another page.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Using the firebug console (or similar) you'll seet the function logs output 'fire!' every 3 seconds
                </p>
                <p>
                    Problem: opening the dialog reloads the page javascript, 
                    creating another interval, fireing the function twice as frequently,
                </p>
            </div><!-- end content-0001 -->
            <div    data-role="footer"
            id="footer-0001"
            >&nbsp;</div><!-- end footer-0001 -->
        </div><!-- end page main-->
    </body>
</html>
```

dialog.html

```
<div data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>A Dialog</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bind `pageinit` to `#pagemain`..`$(document).on('pageinit', '#pagemain', function(event) {` binding `pageinit` to `body` will fire whenever any page is initiated. dialog is a page but in a shape of a dialog, once its loaded into `body`, `pageinit` event will fire and cause repeating `doSomething()` functions.

Comment: another issue, why are you using jQuery migrate and jquery 1.10? jQuery 1.9.1 is enough to work with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2

Comment: Thanks Omar.  I haven't tried what you said.. but having dug deeper into pageinit I know you are right.  I'm moving from jquery .. where I just needed one doc ready for all my <head code.  I realise now in JQM I have to be much pore specific.  and WRT migrate.. yes you're right again .. the code is stripped out of a bigger application that needs migrate for the <head code, but having stripped that out it is not needed.

Comment: If you face any problem, let us know :)